# VB.NET MVC Can't Access Models in Viewmodel?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display the result set of join tables in the view, I approach this by creating a viewmodel that contains two models, developers and reports, and a query in the controller assigns the data to the viewmodel. However it seems like I can't access the models from controller. I wonder if it's possible to do so? if it is what I did wrong?

Report model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Report
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Dev_id As Integer
End Class
```

Developer model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Developer
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property DT_created As DateTime
    Public Property DT_last_modified As DateTime
End Class
```

ViewmodelReport:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class ViewModelReport

    Public Property reports As New Report
    Public Property developers As New Developer

End Class
```

Controller:

```
Namespace Controllers
    Public Class TrackerController
        Inherits Controller

        Dim db As New Analytic

        ' GET: Tracker
        Function Index() As ActionResult

            Dim vm As ViewModelReport = New ViewModelReport()
            Dim rep = From r In db.Reports
                      Join d In db.Developers
                          On r.Dev_id Equals d.Id
                      Join ac In db.Audit_changes
                          On ac.Report_Id Equals r.Id
                      Select New ViewModelReport With {
                          .reports.  ***<----does not show reports properties***
                          }

            Return View(vm)
        End Function
```

Comment: what namespace is `ViewModelReport` in?  Is that namespace referenced (imported) in the controller?

Comment: @David, I didn't define a namespace for `ViewModelReport`, but i'm sure it's referenced because I was able to create an `ViewModelReport` object in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not expect it to show the properties of the report in there.  It is expecting a report variable in the with block.  You should be able to do

.reports = new Report With {.....etc

to assign the values to the report class.